# XPath Not contains text

Tags: xpath, contains

Here is my code:

```
plantas = tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"terreno") or text[not(contains(text(),"terreno"))]]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/text()')
```

How can I make for my xpath to grab the value that precedes the word "terreno" or grab it even though theres no word? My code above is not working.

In the image below, the second one is not grabbing the "1 planta"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the XPath you need (since the previous one seems inconsistent) :

```
//td[@class="tituloresult"]/following::td[@style and contains(text(),"planta")]
```

Works flawlessly on the first 10 pages of your target [website](https://www.avisosdeocasion.com/Resultados-Inmuebles.aspx?n=venta-casas-nuevo-leon&PlazaBusqueda=2&Plaza=2&pagina=1&idinmueble=3&pagfinal=24&paginicial=1&Mosaico=0&scl=0).

Note :
Highlighted ads will be excluded by the XPath expression. So you'll get between 22 and 24 results per page.

EDIT : For the surface area :

```
//td[@class="tituloresult"]/following::td[@style and contains(text(),"terreno")]
```

or (to include elements without text) :

```
//td[@class="tituloresult"]/following::td[@style][3]
```

Comment: But what if there's no text in there? What I'm trying to do is that if there's no text, the value would be 0

Comment: You'll need XPath 2.0 to do this directly but LXML does not support it. What you can do is to process each ad one by one in a loop (for each table... , get the number of plants get the surface area if it exists). Or use  a global XPath `//td[@class="tituloresult"]/following::td[@style][3]` then replace `''` with `0` or `NA` with `replace()`.

Comment: So I've been trying the code to include elements without text (and the others) but I'm getting as an output the following:
`[<Element td at 0x233ce5b4db0>, <Element td at 0x233ce5b4f40>, <Element td at 0x233ce5b49a0>, <Element td at 0x233ce5b4c20>, <Element td at 0x233ce5b4b30>, <Element td at 0x233ce5b4950>, <Element td at 0x233ce5b4720>, <Element td at 0x233ce592b80>, <Element td at 0x233ce5c46d0>, <Element td at 0x233ce5c4ea0>, ...]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EDIT: **I found that I needed to use encode UTF-8**

Comment: You can do : `news = tree.xpath('//td[@class="tituloresult"]/following::td[@style][3]'); for item in news:; print ((item.text).strip())` Output : `300m² terreno,315m² terreno,315m² terreno,150m² terreno,215m² terreno,...`

Comment: I just had time to continue workking on my project. What would be the path for the 'recámaras'? I've been trying to get it but since it doesn't have a @style attribute

Comment: It would be : `//td[@class="tituloresult"]/following::tr[2]//tr[2]/td[1][count(./*)=0]`. Ads with orange background are excluded.

Comment: If I would like to include those (even though I will get empty string as an output), I would only have to erase de [count(...)]? Because the one from surface area and floors/stories include them, because I always get a 24 length output.

Comment: `//td[@class="tituloresult"]/following::td[contains(text(),"cámaras")]` will select 24 results per page (tested OK with the 10 first pages).